# Sending mail via pear mail

Tags: php, email, ssl, pear

Sorry for my English.
I’m trying to sent e-mai via Mail pear packet:

```
require_once "Mail.php";

$from = '<frommail@gmail.com>';
$to = '<tomail@vacant.lv>';
$subject = 'Hi!';
$body = "Hi,\n\nHow are you?";

$headers = array(
    'From' => $from,
    'To' => $to,
    'Subject' => $subject
);

$smtp = Mail::factory('smtp', array(
        'host' => 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com',
        'port' => '465',
        'auth' => true,
        'username' => 'frommail@gmail.com',
        'password' => 'pass'
    ));

$mail = $smtp->send($to, $headers, $body);

if (PEAR::isError($mail)) {
    echo('<p>' . $mail->getMessage() . '</p>');
} else {
    echo('<p>Message successfully sent!</p>');
}

//email addresses are changed
```

But in result I have error:
Failed to connect to ssl://smtp.gmail.com:465 [SMTP: Failed to connect socket: Permission denied (code: -1, response: )]
Openssl is enabled.
Thanks you.

Answer (score 0):

At some stage you might want to send an HTML email, so you would also need to use the Mail/mime package that is provided by PEAR. I've included that as well.

```
<?php
require_once "Mail.php";
require_once "Mail/mime.php";

$from = "<noreply@example.com>";
$to = "fred@example.com"; // the email address
$host = "smtp.gmail.com";
$port = "587";
// use the first example username if sending from gmail, as full email address 
// is required
$username = "fred.flintstone@gmail.com";
$username = "fred";
$password = "secure";
$headers = array ('From' => $from,'To' => $to,'Subject' => $subject);
$mailbody = "<html><body>...</body></html>";

$mime = new Mail_mime();
$mime->setHTMLBody($mailbody);
$body = $mime->get();
$headers = $mime->headers($headers);
$smtp = Mail::factory(
    'smtp',array (
        'host' => $host,
        'auth' => true,
        'username' => $username,
        'password' => $password,
        'port' => $port
    )
);

// send email
$mail = $smtp->send($to, $headers, $body);
if (PEAR::isError($mail)) {
    echo($mail->getMessage());
} else {
    echo "<b><Center>Succesfully sent email to</b>$to</center>";
}
```